# Which ip adress to type when running android app on real device?

Tags: android, mysql, android-emulator, ip-address

In my android app users should type their personal datas and it should be sent to remote database. In order to do that I have created PHP script and AsyncTask class and all the other necessary things. When I run the app on localhost, everything works perfectly.

Here is the line when PHP script is called from android app

```
insert.execute("http://10.0.2.2/registerApp.php");
```

My question is, what IP adress should I type instead of **10.0.2.2** in order tu run my app successfully on real device, not on emulator ??

I am confused, first thing that crossed my mind was that I should type IP adress of my phone device where I am gonna test the app, but then I thought what is gonna happen if I take some other phone device which has different IP adress?

Comment: You'll need to expose your server to the internet in production.  For testing you could host your php on a local network and connect to it on android as long as your using your wifi radio.

Comment: if your server is in localhost try to connect the local server and real device in a common network like wifi. So at that time you will get an ip address in real device. So use this ip when your server  is in localhost. Otherwise Your provide the server ip

Comment: Provided your android device is in the same W(LAN) as your pc you should use the ip address of the server pc. You can find that out on a windows pc with ipconfig. Of course you do not have to expose your server to the internet or other silly things.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what IP adress should I type instead of 10.0.2.2 in order tu run my app successfully on real device, not on emulator ??

The IP address of the 'server' hosting the PHP script.

The address 10.0.2.2 (when used on an emulator) is translated to be the `localhost` address of the PC which the emulator is running on.

If you take the emulator out of the equation, and assuming you're connecting to the 'server' using wired or wireless connection, then you need to use the actual IP address of the PC.

Comment: On which server can I host my app in order to upload it on play store. Till now I run it on wamp server.